# Data filtered by condition and earliest possible day in R

Tags: r

My data looks similar to this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4),
                 name = c('a','a','a','b','c','a','a','b','b','c','a'),
                 date = c('01/01/2023','01/02/2023', '01/03/2023','01/01/2023','01/03/2023',
                          '01/01/2023', '01/03/2023', '01/03/2023','01/02/2023', '01/03/2023','01/01/2023'),
value = c(1:11),
                 days = c(-2, -1, 0, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0,-1, 0, -2))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

```
   ID name       date value days
1   1    a 2023-01-01     1   -2
2   1    a 2023-01-02     2   -1
3   1    a 2023-01-03     3    0
4   1    b 2023-01-01     4   -2
5   1    c 2023-01-03     5    0
6   2    a 2023-01-01     6   -2
7   2    a 2023-01-03     7    0
8   2    b 2023-01-03     8    0
9   2    b 2023-01-02     9   -1
10  3    c 2023-01-03    10    0
11  4    a 2023-01-01    11   -2
```

For each of 4 `ID`s and vailable info from `name` I have to get one row from `value`. The catch here is that it should be based on column `days`, so I get either the earliest value before day == 0, or if that date is not available, I should get value from day == 0. Additionally if for any ID & day == 0 is not available I'd like to get info about this in column `flag` (otherwise NA).

So desired output should look like this:

```
  ID name       date value days     flag
1  1    a 01/02/2023     2   -1     <NA>
2  1    b 01/01/2023     4   -2     <NA>
3  1    c 01/03/2023     5    0     <NA>
4  2    a 01/01/2023     6   -2     <NA>
5  2    b 01/02/2023     9   -1     <NA>
6  3    c 01/03/2023    10    0     <NA>
7  4    a 01/01/2023    11   -2 no day 0
```

Is there any easy way to write this withouth making few subsets and joining them later (that's my only idea so far)? I'm struggling with matching all the criteria and I've tried `rank`, grouping and subsets of data but I'm nowhere near desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using `case_when` to get the right `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(ID, name, date) %>% 
  mutate(iszero = days == 0, 
         flag = if_else(any(iszero), NA, "no day 0"), .by = ID) %>% 
  filter(case_when(n() > 1 & first(!iszero) ~ lead(iszero), 
                   n() > 1 & first(iszero) ~ iszero, 
                   n() == 1 ~ TRUE), .by = c(ID, name)) %>% 
  select(-iszero)
  ID name       date value days     flag
1  1    a 2023-01-02     2   -1     <NA>
2  1    b 2023-01-01     4   -2     <NA>
3  1    c 2023-01-03     5    0     <NA>
4  2    a 2023-01-01     6   -2     <NA>
5  2    b 2023-01-02     9   -1     <NA>
6  3    c 2023-01-03    10    0     <NA>
7  4    a 2023-01-01    11   -2 no day 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We could first add the flag, then `subset` with a clear and readable case handling.

```
> transform(df, flag=ave(days, ID, FUN=\(x) c("no day 0", NA_character_)[
+   any(x == 0) + 1L])) |>
+   subset(days == suppressWarnings(ave(days, ID, name, FUN=\(x) {
+     if (all(x > 0)) {
+       -Inf
+     } else if (all(x == 0)) {
+       x
+     } else if (any(x < 0)) {
+       max(x[x < 0])
+     } else {
+       max(x)
+     }
+   })))
   ID name       date value days     flag
2   1    a 2023-01-02     2   -1     <NA>
4   1    b 2023-01-01     4   -2     <NA>
5   1    c 2023-01-03     5    0     <NA>
6   2    a 2023-01-01     6   -2     <NA>
9   2    b 2023-01-02     9   -1     <NA>
10  3    c 2023-01-03    10    0     <NA>
11  4    a 2023-01-01    11   -2 no day 0
```

*Note:* `ave` internally splits at the `interaction` of *ID* and *name* which can yield elements of length zero and it's defined `max(numeric(0)) == -Inf`. In these cases this yields to a warning in `lapply(with(df, split(days, interaction(ID, name))), max)` but it doesn't affect the result. Because we know the reason we can `suppressWarnings`.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4), name = c("a", 
"a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a"), date = structure(c(19358, 
19359, 19360, 19358, 19360, 19358, 19360, 19360, 19359, 19360, 
19358), class = "Date"), value = 1:11, days = c(-2, -1, 0, -2, 
0, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, -2)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```